# Cannot get rid of an underscore in a simple menu list item or center it either, I mean no matter what

Tags: user-interface, html-lists

I have tried everything, including "text-decoration: none;" and making sure all padding is removed. Should be a pretty basic and elemental procedure but nothing works.

Yes, I have read all I can find here and tried it or looked elsewhere on the net for a solution. Nothing is working.

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css"/>
</head>
<style>

#main-nav {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
width: 100%; 
height: 30px;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #D6D5D6;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-list {
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
width: 1000px;
margin-: auto;
padding: 0;
}

.nav-list > li {
margin: 0;
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
line-height: 30px;
}
.nav-list > li > a {
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 12px;
list-style-image: none;
}
.nav-list > li > a:hover {
background-color: #FFF;
}

#dropdown {
position: relative;
top: 30px;
width: 100px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
color: #F00;
}
.dropdown: li{
background-color:#697;
position:relaive;
width:200px;
height:30px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown: li a {
color: #ddd;
text-decoration:none;
position: absolute;
width:200px;
height:30px;
padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown: li a:hover {
background-color: #CCC;
}

body {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
#transbar {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
width: 1000px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
#wrap {
width: 1000px;
top: 668px;
position: absolute;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
#textbox {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-style: normal;
height: 575px;
width: 1000px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
}

</style>

<div id="wrapper">
<body>

<nav class="main-nav">
<ul class="nav-list">
<li><a href="#">About</a>
<ul style="list-style: none;" class="dropdown">
li><a href="#">The Film</a></li>
<li><a href="#">The Park</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Updates</a>
<ul style="list-style: none;" "dropdown">
<li><a href="slieshow.htm.">Slideshow</a><li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Trailers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your *CSS* to remove underline effect for `<li>` links:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

As for displaying `<li>` elements in the center of the page I've provided a simplified version of your code that centers each `<li>`.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Film</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Park</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
    <li><a href="slieshow.htm.">Slideshow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Trailers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
a:link {
   text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
   text-align: center;
   list-style-type: none; 
}
ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

NOTE: you may want to adapt this to your current code, next time you ask a question like this probably best to post a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of your code.

Comment: Works sweetly for all underscores, but now I have bullets next to each entry on the top of each menu list, and there is still the problem of centering the drop down items. Thanks for this pointer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @IanAnthony I've just updated answer, basically add list-style: none; to the ul css styling to remove bullet-points

Comment: Sweet. Bullets and underscores gone! The only problem now is the items in the submenu, the listed items appear left aligned and indented from the left. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: @IanAnthony I'm not really sure about what your project is currently like or what you want it to be like, that's why I just provided a simplified html/css example. if you could provide a jsfiddle example maybe, just need to create an account then upload your code and then provide us with a link to that example. otherwise, all I can assume is that you have float:left or margin:left that is left-aligning/indenting list items. hope that helps

Comment: Ok. I will look into this jsfiddle thingy asap. I'm fooling around with some things in the meantime. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Fooling around with the width in the CSS "Box" attribute did the trick. I am using Dreamweaver as my text editor, btw. A width of 123px added to the ul CSS script did it for the first listed column. For the ul li column I had to mess with that as well. A measure of 68px on the width centered that. I don't know why this works, and as you tell I'm a novice at this.